# method result type

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In the following code the method `array1` won't return the avarage because its return type is `void`.

I know what `void` means but can someone explain to me what is a void result type and how to make this method return the avarage:

```
public class JavaApplication4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4};

    double result = array1 (a);
}

public static array1 (int[] b) {
    double avarage;
    int total = 0;
    for (int x:b) {
        total += x;
    }

avarage = total / b.length;
return avarage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A return type of void means that a method doesn't return anything.  This is useful when you want to preform an operation on an array, but there isn't any value associated with the operation.  For example, say that you wanted to swap the first and last element in an array, you could write some method like this (ignore the necessary error checking)

```
 public void swapArrayLocs(int[] swapping){
      int temp = swapping[0];
      swapping[0] = swapping[swapping.length - 1];
      swapping[swapping.length - 1] = temp;
 }
```

When you call this method, you're not expecting any sort of result from it, you're expecting your program to just take care of business and continue executing.

In this case, you actually want your array1(int[]) method to make its available to the rest of the program.  You do this by specifying the return type of the function, which tells the rest of the program what type of information you expect that function to return.  In your case, you'd do this by changing your method declaration to.

```
public static double array1(int[] b){
    //the same method body
}
```

Note how in this case the word double is inserted after static.  This tells the calling function that when it executes array1, the method will give back a value of type double.  Contrast this with what you had before which said that the method would not give back any type of information.

Answer (score 3):

The "result type" or "return type" is set in the function declaration. It just means what type of data is going to be returned after the function is called. Your function should look like:

```
public static double array1(int[] b) {
    double average;
    int total=0;
    for(int x:b){
        total +=x;
    }
    average = (double) total/b.length;

    return average;
}
```

This will return the value of average after the function is done. So result will hold the same thing as the final value of average after the function completes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `array1` as returning `double`. Change its declaration to:

```
public static double array1(int [] b ) {
```

A `void` function -- `void array1(...)` -- does not return a value.

Note that there's another error in your code:

```
avarage = total / b.length;
```

The above uses integer division, meaning that the result is truncated to integer, and only then converted to `double`. To fix, change the line to:

```
avarage = total / (double)b.length;
```

Comment: so if i dont set the method to double it will be treated as void ?

Comment: @AhmadDawod: No it won't be. Your code doesn't compile (`Return type for the method is missing`).